# How to avoid Image Change when Screen Open in android?

Tags: android

I Have an Issue with some Image ,scenario is that when screen opens I have set multiple Images in Listview ,but some time One of the Image changes automatically .How to avoid this problem.

```
private static final String[] itemname = new String[]{"Invite by Facebook",
        "Invite by Whatsapp",
        "Invite by Email",
        "More options"
};
View header;
private ListView m_listView;
private Integer[] imgid = {
        R.drawable.facebook,
        R.drawable.whatsapp,
        R.drawable.em,
        R.drawable.share

};
private Integer[] imgArrow = {
        R.drawable.arrow, R.drawable.arrow, R.drawable.arrow, R.drawable.arrow
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.refer_earn);
    init();

}

private void init() {
    Toolbar m_Toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(m_Toolbar);
    //noinspection ConstantConditions,ConstantConditions
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    CReferAndEarnAdpater adapter = new CReferAndEarnAdpater(this, itemname, imgid, imgArrow);
    m_listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    //code to add header and footer to listview
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.snippet_item2, m_listView,
            false);
    m_listView.addHeaderView(header, null, false);


    m_listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

}
here is adapter code:-

```
private  Activity context;
private  String[] itemname;
private  Integer[] imgid;
private  Integer[] imgArrow;

public CReferAndEarnAdpater(Activity context, String[] itemname, Integer[] imgid, Integer[] imgArrow) {
    super(context, R.layout.refer_item, itemname);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    this.context=context;
    this.itemname=itemname;
    this.imgid=imgid;
    this.imgArrow = imgArrow;
}

public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.refer_item, null, true);

    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    ImageView arrow = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.arrow);

    txtTitle.setText(itemname[position]);
    imageView.setImageResource(imgid[position]);
    arrow.setImageResource(imgArrow[position]);

    Animation animation = null;
    animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,R.anim.push_up_in);
    animation.setDuration(1000);
    rowView.startAnimation(animation);
    return rowView;

};
```

}

Comment: post your screenshot

Comment: please, show you code?

Comment: may be issue of your adapter of list-view please post code

Comment: Its magic!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Viewholder` approach here.

```
private class ViewHolder {
    TextView textView;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = View.inflate(mcontext, R.layout.your_layout, null);
        viewHolder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.your_textView);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.textView.setText(data.get(position).getText());

    return convertView;
}
```

Your code might call findViewById() frequently during the scrolling of ListView, which can slow down performance. Even when the Adapter returns an inflated view for recycling, you still need to look up the elements and update them. A way around repeated use of findViewById() is to use the "view holder" design pattern.

A ViewHolder object stores each of the component views inside the tag field of the Layout, so you can immediately access them without the need to look them up repeatedly.

[More details you can find here](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html)